# Ajax cause requestAnimationFrame error

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I'm facing an error after I implement Ajax code into my website can please someone help me identify what and where the error come from, Thanks a lot in advance

Below is my Ajax code

```
  $(document).ready(function() {

    $(".desc").click(function() 
    {
      var _id = $(this);

      $.ajax({
          type: "GET",
          url: "../ppuyakul/php/loadProduct.php",
          data: {id: _id},
          success: function(data)
          {
            $("#detail").html(data);

          }});

    });
  });
```

And here is my error

```
jquery.min.js:4 Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'requestAnimationFrame' on 'Window': 1 argument required, but only 0 present.
        at e (jquery.min.js:4)
        at Ab (jquery.min.js:4)
        at Ab (jquery.min.js:4)
        at Ab (jquery.min.js:4)
        at Function.r.param (jquery.min.js:4)
        at Function.ajax (jquery.min.js:4)
        at cata_main.php:31
        at e (jquery.min.js:4)
        at Ab (jquery.min.js:4)
        at Ab (jquery.min.js:4)
```

Comment: can you show the HTML where you get `_id` from ? most likely, the var is empty : what kind of element do you want to get the ID from (div, input) ?

Comment: @OldPadawan yup Thanks for point it out it's an error right there at `_id` now i fix it with a proper declaration so the error is now gone ^^" thanks a lot for you help, really appreciated =)